# How to fix local Firebase DB connectivity with firebase-admin ^8.9.0

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

I have a working production Firebase Node server that I have working locally. My UAT version does not work locally, it times out trying to access my Firebase documents (Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded). After working through this issue after the original posting **here** it looks like the node_modules folder that I created originally, with the configuration below will allow local connection, but any upgrade or modification does not work.  The second configuration is an example of this. In other words if I copy the node_modules folder to another directory that has my source code, then run

> firebase serve

it works, but if I run npm update, then I time out trying to access Firebase DB documents.

```
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^3.0.4",
    "actions-on-google": "^2.10.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "fast-xml-parser": "^3.12.20",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.0.0",
    "firebase-client": "0.1.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",

    "request-promise-native": "^1.0.7",
    "sprintf-js": "^1.1.2",
    "stream-buffers": "^3.0.2",
    "twilio": "^3.32.0"
 },



  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^3.0.4",
    "actions-on-google": "^2.10.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "fast-xml-parser": "^3.12.20",
    "firebase-admin": "8.0.0",
    "firebase-client": "0.1.1",
    "firebase-functions": "3.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "request-promise-native": "^1.0.7",
    "sprintf-js": "^1.1.2",
    "stream-buffers": "^3.0.2",
    "twilio": "^3.32.0"
  },
```

I attempted to upgrade one dependency at a time, starting with firebase-functions, and that upgraded my firebase-admin to 8.9.0, so I'm sort of assuming it's firebase-admin though I suppose it could be firebase-functions.

In either case I'd like to be up-to-date, but being able to test locally is critical.

Comment: Without some sort of error message or indicator of what's broken, there's not much we can do to help.  Could you edit the question to be specific about what's not working the way you expect?

Comment: I've edited to provide more information and more circumstances.